# Pass two parameters into a url element while running the loop to webscrape data

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

```py
import requests
for i in range(len(lat_lon_df)):
    lat,lon = lat_lon_df.iloc[i]
    try:
        page = requests.get("https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat={}&lon={}&unit=0&lg=english&FcstType=graphical".format(lat).format(lon))
        print(page)
    except:
        continue
```

```
   Lat          Long
```

0   55.999722   -161.207778

1   60.891854   -161.392330

2   60.890632   -161.199325

3   54.143012   -165.785368

4   62.746967   -164.602280

I am trying to run a loop to scrape data while taking new latitude and longitude parameters for every iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one time `format`, information can be found [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/):

```
page = requests.get("https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat={}&lon={}&unit=0&lg=english&FcstType=graphical".format(lat, lon))
```

Alternative:

```
page = requests.get(f"https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&unit=0&lg=english&FcstType=graphical")
```